# Why was this closed as "non-computer-related" on superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, moderation, questions

Please see https://superuser.com/questions/20423/your-experiences-with-self-publishing-sites-blurb-lulu-com-etc

Note: I didn't ask the question, nor do I give much a darn about the answer, but I did up-vote the question and suggest it was legit to ask.  Apparently I was wrong.

I'm confused as to why it was closed.  Why would asking a question about sites (with software) that help you publish a book be *not computer related*?  Publishing requires software in this day and age, and I've seen people asking questions that survive and thrive about other web-based services such as Blogger, Google Reader, mail hosts, etc.  Those services are also web-based and let folks do things like *read and write blogs*, and *read and write mail*.  If self-publishing isn't computer related, how can those be?

Please educate me.  I'm not looking for a reversal on the decision -- I don't care about the *instance* having been garbage collected -- but to grok the community garbage-collection process *in general*.  Thanks!

---

**Update:**
OK, so I *think* I get it.  Let me synthesize/rephrase.  From the answers you've provided, it seems:

- There are *multiple* issues with the question under the microscope that make it overall just *not a good question*.
- "Not computer related" was but *one reason of many*, and perhaps the simplest or most obvious reason at hand to close it with.
- Nobody should expect an exhaustive summary of everything wrong with a question when it's closed.  I suppose moderation wouldn't scale well if such was required.
- Odds are good that a *similar but better-phrased* question might actually have survived moderation *on the same substance of the matter* simply by having been more specific or worded better.

Comment: Don'tcha love it ... even this meta-discussion *about* the question having been closed has been down-voted !  LOL

Comment: @cwrea: What did you expect? For everyone to agree with you?

Comment: No, of course, I don't expect that. :-) IMHO, voting on *questions* shouldn't be an issue of "agreement" -- I personally don't vote for questions based on whether or not I *agree* with the asker, but whether the *question itself* is relevant and makes sense to ask.  I vote **answers** on whether I agree, or not.  But, I suppose what you allude to is that some people use the question vote to indicate agreement or disagreement.  So it goes, I suppose.

Comment: @cwrea: Well, you are on meta now, and that is specifically how meta works. Maybe you should lurk more?

Comment: @Rich B: 'k, lurking more.  :-)

Comment: RE: Odds are good that a similar but better-phrased question might actually have survived moderation on the same substance of the matter simply by having been more specific or worded better. - does this mean SO discriminates against non-English speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, it is just a bad question, extremely vague and not asking a single actual question.

If it were "How do you post an image in WordPress?" it may have had a chance. That question clearly exists only to try and get a discussion about the blog software, which is discouraged there.

Comment: I specifically liked your choice of words: "If nothing else, [...]" and "[...] it may have had a chance."

Answer (score 2):

The most cited sentence of the FAQ:

> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.

This question meets these criteria.
Why it is closed with the reason "not computer related"? You can argue, yes, but choosing a publishing site has nothing to do with fixing a computer problem, workaround a software issue or gaining a deeper understanding of your system. Not a complete list, but that's what SuperUser is for.

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction was that the question looked like a shill for the company concerned.

Basically, it's not a question. It's not a bad subject for a question, but it's just not a question that will fit the model for SO/SF/SU/MSO - it needs to be rephrased:

- How did you make Lulu do *something or other*
- I did this on Blurb and *something unexpected* occured, any ideas?
- There's this other book publishing site that seems better in some piece of functionality than this other site, can someone highlight the differences.

There's even a case for:

> I'm setting up a book publishing site, could people highlight how existing suppliers fall down?

**Summary:** What I can't grok is why would someone unconnected with a site in this space would ask this sort of question.

Comment: Well, SuperUser doesn't have *any* subjective questions! http://superuser.com/search?q=best This seems like a perfectly valid question, looking for recommendations for a service to (self-)publish a book (although it could be worded better)

Comment: @dbr: when all you have to go by is text, wording is *everything*...

Comment: Lack of subjective questions only means someone's not used a tag, not because they're banned!

Comment: If you're writing your own book, one would hope you're good at saying what you mean :-)